# JsonMappingException even if checking for null values

Tags: java, json

I am getting an exception when doing a null and empty check for a string that I am passing to an ObjectMapper Json Parser method. This is my code here:

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayStuff(
            @RequestParam(value = "item") int itemCode) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {


           if (!text.equals("") || text != null) {
                JsonNode jsonThresholds = OBJECT_MAPPER.readTree(text);
                do stuff()..

          }else {
               do nothing();
          }
     }
```

I am getting this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@182d2fd7; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2782)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1659)
```

Could someone please explain to me what is happening and how I can fix this.

Thankyou

Comment: show json string please.

Comment: something like this: { "happy" : 3, "sad" : 4, "ok" : 5 }

Comment: change it to !text.equals("") && text != null that may work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
!text.equals("") || text != null
```

to

```
text != null && !text.equals("")
```

because even `text=""` then text `!= null` become true and goes to inside of if..

you should first check null or not because if value is null .equls will give `nullpointer exception`

this is wrong too

```
 !text.equals("")  &&  text != null 
       ↑
     null pointer Exception can be occurred here
```

Comment: perhaps `text.trim().equals("")`, to get rid of the empty space

Comment: Thank you, it works for empty strings but if there is no string, I still get a null pointer exception. Why would this be?

Comment: obj.toString().equals("{}"); this could be what u looking for in that case.

Comment: @LiluPatel `OBJECT_MAPPER` is `null` then

Comment: I am creating a new objectmapper like this: private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox so there is no scope that objectmapper can be null

Comment: @LiluPatel check my updated answer .actually you should swap null check and empty check.first you should check null or not